# How do I create an empty solution in Visual Studio (2008)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am unable to create an empty solution in Visual Studio. The msdn documentation says this is possible but fails to mention how. (Where I have looked, anyway..)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

File --> New Project

Under Projects Type, Select 'Other Project Types' --> Visual Studio Solutions

You should see it on the right!

[image: Take a look here]

Comment: Thanks!
In VS 2010 it's the same BTW.

Comment: The solution is created in its own subdirectory., i. e. in D:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Solution1\Solution1.sln

Comment: Wow, speaking of mislabeling, hah?

Answer (score 6):

New project > Other > Visual Studio Solutions > Empty Solution

Answer (score 2):

well to me

create a new project...
then create another project and add it to the first one (do not create a second one)
only after doing this I were able to see the the solution icon and the text 'Solution 'xxxxxx' (2 projects)'...